# autowire bytype fails incase of interface implementations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am currently learning Spring AutoWiring Concept. I came across a situation. I created a `Engine` interface and then two implementations of this Interface one being `FerrariEngine` and another as `HondaEngine`. Now I am trying to autowire this in `Car` class using `autowire="byType"` in `xml` config. But the code is throwing the error as `Engine` is null. Is it that Spring cannot identify interface implemented class using byType??

Please help me in understanding why this error is occuring.

`Car.java`

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
//@Component
public class Car {
    // @Autowired
    private Engine engine;

    public void printEngineName() {
        System.out.println(engine.getEngineName());
    }
}
```

`Engine.java`

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


public interface Engine {
    String getEngineName();
}
```

`FerrariEngine.java`

```java
public class FerrariEngine implements Engine {
    @Override
    public String getEngineName() {
        return "FerrariEngine";
    }
}
```

`HondaEngine.java`

```java
public class HondaEngine implements Engine {

    @Override
    public String getEngineName() {
        return "HondaEngine";
    }
}
```

`Driver.java`

```java
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/primaryautowire.xml");
        Car car1 = (Car) context1.getBean("car");
        /*
         * String[] beanNames = context1.getBeanDefinitionNames();
         * for(String name: beanNames)
         * System.out.println(name);
         */
        car1.printEngineName();
    }
}
```

`primaryautowire.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
>

    <bean class="Spring3AdvancedWiring.primarybean.HondaEngine" primary="true">
</bean>

    <bean class="Spring3AdvancedWiring.primarybean.FerrariEngine">
</bean>

    <bean id="car" class="Spring3AdvancedWiring.primarybean.Car" autowire="byType">
</bean>

    <!--<context:annotation-config/>-->
</beans>
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Spring3AdvancedWiring.primarybean.Engine.getEngineName()" because "this.engine" is null
    at Spring3AdvancedWiring.primarybean.Car.printEngineName(Car.java:14)
    at Spring3AdvancedWiring.primarybean.Driver.main(Driver.java:20)
```

Comment: YOu aren't autowiring anything. There is no setter, so no way for the XML way to determine what to inject (hence `null`), if you add `@Autowired` without explicitly enabling it with either `<context:annotation-config />` or by `<context:component-scan />` it won't work either as it won't proces `@Autowired` without that.